# looking for tricky sql query solution

Tags: mysql

i'm having the following database structure (for messaging):

```
id   from_userid   to_userid   time_stamp   message
```

let's say i'm user with id 1 and i want to get a list of ALL user_ids i've been interacting with, sorted by timestamp - any idea how to do it?

thanks

Comment: ``from_id`` and ``to_id`` are ids of users?

Comment: yes (will update post)

Comment: let's say you tried something, what would it be?

Comment: i've made 2 views and tried combining then by a 3rd one but didn't succeed .. :/

Comment: Can you reach a user indirect (through more then one edge)?

Comment: select distinct id, timestamp from (that table) where to_userid = '1' OR from_userid = '1' order by time_stamp; won't work?

Comment: Either we don't understand what you want, or this isn't really a "tricky" query (or your standard for "tricky" is very low).

Comment: i think the hard thing is to merging/union 2 different queries which are sorted by timestamp .. o_O

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
 SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT from_id AS id, time_stamp
       FROM <table>
      WHERE to_id=<user id>
      UNION
     SELECT to_id AS id, time_stamp
       FROM <table>
      WHERE from_id=<user id>
   ) AS t
ORDER BY time_stamp
```

Comment: No `FROM` clauses in the subquery?

Comment: this seems the right way but it's giving me an error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE from_userid = 1 OR to_userid = 1
ORDER by time_stamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

- select all values + timestamps where "me" is from_userid
- select all values + timestamps where "me" is to_userid
- in both selects assign the same name to the "other" user id
- join the result sets using UNION ALL
- then order the result by the timestamp column
- group by user id and min(timestamp)

In sql it would be something like this:

```
select rel_user, min(time_stamp) as first_contact from 
  ( 
    select time_stamp, to_userid as rel_user where from_userid=my_ID
     union all 
    select time_stamp, from_userid as rel_user where to_userid=my_ID
  )
 group by rel_user
 order by min(time_stamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the other ways use more than one SELECT here's one using CASE

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN to_userid=1 THEN from_userid
    ELSE to_userid
FROM table WHERE to_userid=1 OR from_userid=1 ORDER BY time_stamp
```

Comment: IMHO To complicated for no benefit.

Comment: IMO it's easier to understand than doing multiple selects and unions to make it work